# Change return value of final class in tests

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Does somebody know how to change the return value of the method in the final class.

I'm trying to test the `ToBeTested` class and I want to get true as the result.
I tried to use `Powermockito` but didn't find a solution.

```
public final class ToBeChanged {

    public static boolean changeMyBehaviour() {
        return false;
    }
}

public class ToBeTested {
    public boolean doSomething () {
        if (ToBeChanged.changeMyBehaviour)
            return false;
        else 
            return true;
    }
}
```

I do not want to declare the `ToBeChanged` class as a field in the `ToBeTested` class.
So there is no way to change the implemented classes itself.

Comment: Can you post the PowerMockito code you tried?

Comment: I doubt you can do anything here as the class is final.

Comment: *Why* don't you want to use the normal way of making code testable? The tight coupling you've got (via a static method) is fundamentally making your code hard to test - so what's your objection to changing that?

Comment: The basic rule says: If the code is not testable the code is not good. Refactor it. If it's a third party library and you are stuck with it use PowerMock. It can be achieved with it.

Comment: By myself i wouldn´t write it this way or rewrite it, but i can´t. Can you suggest a example with PowerMock? I tried but didn´t find a solution. The JMockito example below worked for me right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the JMockit tool, the test would be like this:

```
@Test
public void doSomething(@Mocked ToBeChanged mock)
{
    new NonStrictExpectations() {{ ToBeChanged.changeMyBehaviour(); result = true; }};

    boolean res = new ToBeTested().doSomething();

    assertTrue(res);
}
```

Comment: This Solution looks really good. I´d like to plus it but i don´t have enough reputation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hide the static dependency behind an interface. Mock the interface.

Since you don't want to have a field on your class, simply pass the interface as a method parameter (alternatively get an instance through a factory, just don't use tight coupling)

```
public final class ToBeChanged {

    public static boolean changeMyBehaviour() {
        return false;
    }
}

public interface MyInterface {

    boolean changeMyBehaviour();

}

public class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {

    @Override
    public boolean changeMyBehaviour() {
        return ToBeChanged.changeMyBehaviour();
    }

}

class ToBeTested {
    public boolean doSomething (MyInterface myInterface) {
        return !myInterface.changeMyBehaviour();
    }
}

class TheTest {
    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        MyInterface myMock = mock(MyInterface.class);
        when(myMock.changeMyBehaviour()).thenReturn(true);
        new ToBeTested().doSomething(myMock);
    }
}
```

Comment: With this possibility you change the signature of the method, don´t you?

Comment: I do, but if you want to stick to tight coupling, you're simply making life hard for yourself, I'm afraid. If you want to hardwire the dependency, I think you should test with the hardwired dependency.